# How to change a decision tree diagram

Tags: r, decision-tree

[image]

I am using the `ctree` function from the `partykit` package in R to predict something. How can I change the decision tree lower part to bar chart?

The following is part of my code:

```
library(partykit)

myf <- Genre~ Platform+Global_Sales

sks_ctree<- ctree(myf,data=train.data)

table(predict(sks_ctree),train.data$Platform)

plot(sks_ctree)
```

Comment: Hey there and welcome to StackOverflow. Did you know you can use Markdown to format your question? Like using `![description](url)` for images or `\`\`\`` for starting a code paragraph?

Comment: Also, you probably want to provide an exemple people can reproduce, using some classical data from R, like `iris` or `cars`. It will make more probable that people take the time to investigate your question.

Comment: And last, you are using some non-standard functions like `ctree()`, but you do not tell where this functions come from. Which package did you use? The general idea is: try to make it as easy as possible for the people coming to help you.

Comment: hi, thank for your reply sorry about i am newbie at this website and R,i will improve myself.

Comment: `library(party)
sks<- read.csv("C:/Users/User/Desktop/dataset/test11.csv")
set.seed(1234)
ind <-sample(2,nrow(sks),replace=TRUE, prob=c(0.7,0.30))
train.data <-sks[ind==1,]
test.data <-sks[ind==2,]
myf <- Genre~ Platform+Global_Sales
sks_ctree<- ctree(myf,data=train.data)
table(predict(sks_ctree),train.data$Platform)

plot(sks_ctree)
testpred <- predict(sks_ctree,newdata=test.data)
table(testpred,test.data$Platform)
)`
 this is all about my R code, i am using game platform as dependent, genre and global salas as the independent to making the decision tree

Comment: You can update your question by clicking on "edit"!